# How can we extract keys from the json document of cosmos db?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My cosmos db document receives data from multiple IoT devices with one example as shown below-

```json
{
    "messageId": "248",
    "deviceId": "Raspberry Pi Temperature Client",
    "temperature": 21.423303996339754,
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2021-11-26T11:36:33.2589804Z",
    "PartitionId": 0,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2021-11-26T11:36:33.0910000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
        "MessageId": null,
        "CorrelationId": null,
        "ConnectionDeviceId": "TempIoTDevice",
        "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637710970388320856",
        "EnqueuedTime": "2021-11-26T11:36:33.0920000Z"
    },
    "id": "52a61418-5989-4027-80cb-e56a1d5a847c"
}
```

I wanted to extract just the keys from this json as output, something like this -

```json
{
    "messageId",
    "deviceId",
    "temperature",
    "EventProcessedUtcTime",
    "PartitionId",
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime",
    "IoTHub": {
        "MessageId",
        "CorrelationId",
        "ConnectionDeviceId",
        "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId",
        "EnqueuedTime"
    },
    "id"
}
```

How can we achieve this in cosmos db?
Also can we achieve the same with extracting only few columns such as temperature?

Comment: What platform are you using to access CosmosDB? Get document as a stream (don't use the client library to deserialise) and then using as JSON parser for your platform.

Comment: My IoT devices are registered in an IoT hub in the Azure portal and all the devices send data to the hub which is connected to a stream analytics job, which takes all the data and dumps it into the CosmosDB. There is no application involved as of now, all is handled in the Azure portal itself, but I will integrate an app that will run and call these services.

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for you to enumerate all properties of every document. You'd need to do this on your own (and how you accomplish that is a fairly broad topic with no single, objectively-correct answer). I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68036281/272109) to a near-identical question, stating the same thing. Not sure what you mean by "extracting only [a] few columns such as temperature" - this seems like a general query question (maybe ask as a separate question?)

Comment: Why do you you want information?  Is this an XY problem?